# How to run ASP.NET MVC project without IIS on pc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC web project. I want to run my web project without IIS.

How to do this? I do not have a server computer.

Comment: Client Windows also have iis, just install it from windows component installer.

Comment: Take a look at [Running Web Application Locally (Offline) & without IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449992/running-web-application-locally-offline-without-iis)

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS even though you do not have server computer, you can run it on your computer IIS. Windows comes with IIS feature, you just need to enable it. You can refer to [this document](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/web-adaptor/latest/install/iis/enable-iis-10-components-server.htm) about how to enable IIS of your windows computer.

If you do not want to use IIS although you can enable IIS of windows, the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449992/running-web-application-locally-offline-without-iis) provided by M. Mohabbati is a solution which you can refer to.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But ı have developt the project for more then one electronic device. Maybe server not or project run on ios or android. I want to developt web project and run windows,ios,android. This mvc project run tablet. How can ı do ?

Comment: @Ugurarslan: a MVC app run on Android? Sounds implausible.